# How do I build a collection of Users for an Organization using a bootstrap modal with Remote: :true set?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, restful-authentication, bootstrap-modal

I have a rails app with authentication loosely based on the Hartl course. I diverged from that by creating the concept of an Organization, which has_many Users. Upon first creating an account the User becomes Admin of the Organization and is able to add other Users that belong_to the same Organization. All of this works fine, when passing to the website/organizations/organization_id/users/new route.

I have recently begun adding Javascript/AJAX functionality so the User does not need to keep moving from page to page in order to build up their information in the app. This works fine for e.g. Companies (an Organization has_many Companies, and any User can add new ones via a Modal). For some reason it falls down when I try to add Users to the collection, although I do recall this being an issue when I first set up the functionality too. Can you help?

Organization.rb:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :companies, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :products, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :competitors, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
after_create :set_admin

def users_for_form
 collection = users.where(organization_id: id)

 collection.any? ? collection : users.build
end

private   
 def set_admin
 if   self.users.count == 1
   self.users.first.update_attribute(:admin, true)
 else
 return true
 end
end

end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope { order('name ASC') }
belongs_to :organization
has_many :sales_opportunities
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_destroy :allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :organization, presence: true


def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

    def allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
        admin = self.organization.users.find_by(admin: :true)
        self.sales_opportunities.each do |sale|
            sale.update_attributes(user_id: admin.id)
        end
    end
end
```

Users Controller (I've commented out the code which used to work when passing to another page):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
 before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :show]
 before_action :admin_user,    only: :destroy

def index 
 @user = current_user
 organization = current_user.organization_id
 @users = User.joins(:organization).where(organizations: {id: organization})
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @organization = @user.organization
  @user.destroy
  flash[:success] = "User successfully deleted - please re-allocate any sales opportunities they were working on."
  redirect_to @organization
end

def new
 if signed_in?
   @user = User.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])
 else
    @user = User.new
  end
end

def edit
end

def update
 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def create 
 if signed_in?
  # @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  # @user = @organization.users.new(user_params)
  @organization = current_user.organization
  @user = User.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])
   if @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @organization, :flash => {:success => "You added a new user to your organization. Send them their login details today!"} }
      #flash[:success] = "You added a new user to your organization. Send them their login details today!"
      #redirect_to @organization
      format.js 
    end
   else
    render 'new'
   end
  else
   @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
     sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My app! This is your profile page, be sure to take a look at the support link in the footer"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end
end

private
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, organization_attributes: [:organization_name, :organization_id])

end

#before filters

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
  store_location
  redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
 end
end

def admin_user
 redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @organization = @user.organization
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not permitted to visit that page. Please create an account or sign in" unless current_user?(@user) || @user.organization == current_user.organization
 end

end
```

My Modal for adding a new user remotely:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'user'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name, :class => "control-label" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's their name?" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email, :class => "control-label" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Enter their email address" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password, :class => "control-label" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Provide a password" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Repeat Password", :class => "control-label" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
                </div>
                <div id="organization_id" data-organizationid="<%= @current_user.organization.id %>">
                     <%= f.hidden_field :organization_id%>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Add new user account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
            <% end %>
```

The Organization id is passed using Javascript (which is working):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#user_modal').on('show');
 $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
$("#user_name").focus();
});
 var Org;
Org = $('#organization_id').attr('data-organizationid');
//pass the organization_id to the hidden text box
$('#user_organization_id').val(Org);
});
```

Here's the form that is working (if I go to another page) to add users to the organization:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add more users to your organization') %>
  <div class-"container-fluid">
    <h1>Sign up colleagues using the form below:</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="well">
            <%= form_for([:organization, @user], :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's their name?" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Enter their email address" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Provide a password" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Repeat Password", :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Add new user account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the error message from the console in Chrome dev tools:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send 
jQuery.extend.ajax 
$.rails.rails.ajax 
$.rails.rails.handleRemote 
(anonymous function) 
jQuery.event.dispatch 
elemData.handle
```

Here's the logs from the actual console:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-20 12:47:45 +0800
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"MOdal", "email"=>"Modal@m.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add new user account"}
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '99d9db74b7ede7ae2d6fdec02451c92e9c3ade1d'  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1
Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms
```

Let me know if you need more information. I'm not really sure why this wouldn't work (the big change here is that in the html form I use:

```
<%= form_for([:organization, @user], :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Whereas in the remote modal I use:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'user'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

The reason for this change is that the modal doesn't work if I use [:organization, @user] for some reason.

Apologies for the wall of text, and if I've missed anything essential please let me know and I'll edit the post. Any help would be very gratefully received as I've been banging my head against a wall with this all weekend.

Thanks!

Comment: In case it makes things easier - the modal doesn't do anything when I click "Add new User". It remains on the page, open, filled with all the User info I typed in before trying to submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally managed to solve this. The first issue was with the modal form - it needed the following code to use the route organizations/organization_id/users/new:

```
<%= form_for([@organization, @user], :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'user'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

This was throwing some strange errors, which turned out to be due to the Javascript call to re-render the page. In my Organization controller I'd defined the organization.users as @users_index (which was obviously dumb in hindsight as that's already a controller action), and I was rendering this via a partial that couldn't be accessed by my Users controller (it was in the Organization's view file). So the solution was to move it to the shared folder as "users_list", and to add the definition:

```
@users_list = @organization.users
```

To my Users create action. Everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (failed) validation check for email uniqueness:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Apparently the new `User` has a blank email address, and another user with a blank email already exists.

Check your `params` to see if all the form data is coming through.

---

### Edit

Looks like those params are not being passed into a new `User` object in the controller:

```
def create 
  if signed_in?
    # ...
    @user = User.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id]) 
    # ...
```

New users will have an `organization_id`, **all other attributes will be *nil***.

You probably want to do this:

```
def create 
  if signed_in?
    # ...
    @user = User.new(user_params)                    
    @user.organization_id = params[:organization_id] 
    # ...
```

Comment: It is coming through - you can see the email address in the following log: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"Modal", "email"=>"Modal@m.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add new user account"}` - any other ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try. Last night I managed to get the User objects to be submitted to the database by changing the modal form_for to the following: `<%= form_for([@organization, @user], :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'user'}, remote: true) do |f| %>` but this was still creating some issues with the return Javascript (mostly because it's trying to render a partial that's in the Organizations view folder from the Users controller. I'll see whether your suggestion helps me bypass this issue.